# TPU core error on Google Cloud Platform (Cannot find any TPU cores in the system. Please double check Tensorflow master address and TPU worker)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nlp, machine-translation, tpu

The error message is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_classifier.py", line 914, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "./run_classifier.py", line 839, in main
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2876, in train
    rendezvous.raise_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/error_handling.py", line 131, in raise_errors
    six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2871, in train
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 364, in train
    hooks.extend(self._convert_train_steps_to_hooks(steps, max_steps))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2746, in _convert_train_steps_to_hooks
    if ctx.is_running_on_cpu():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_context.py", line 442, in is_running_on_cpu
    self._validate_tpu_configuration()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_context.py", line 613, in _validate_tpu_configuration
    'are {}.'.format(tpu_system_metadata.devices))
RuntimeError: Cannot find any TPU cores in the system. Please double check Tensorflow master address and TPU worker(s). Available devices are (_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
, CPU, 268435456, 8731946518164767128), _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 14576891077092876257)).
```

I am trying to run the example of the paper([bert-gcn-for-paper-citation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06464))

They open the source code on GitHub(https://github.com/TeamLab/bert-gcn-for-paper-citation) 
so I followed the readme and run the code on Google Cloud Platform(GCP) and got the error.

Before running the code, I checked the [BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert) and [GAE](https://github.com/tkipf/gae) on the GCP because the paper and code are built on these algorithms.
BERT and GAE run successfully. (Followed GCP page about the BERT tutorial https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert)

BERT and BERT-GCN have almost the same flags.

BERT example code

```
python3 ./bert/run_classifier.py \
--task_name=${TASK_NAME} \
--do_train=true \
--do_eval=true \
--data_dir=$GLUE_DIR/${TASK_NAME} \
--vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt \
--max_seq_length=128 \
--train_batch_size=32 \
--learning_rate=2e-5 \
--num_train_epochs=3.0 \
--output_dir=${STORAGE_BUCKET}/${TASK_NAME}-output/ \
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu_name=$TPU_NAME
```

and I slightly changed it for BERT-GCN (added last 3 flags)

```
python3 ./run_classifier.py \
--task_name=${TASK_NAME} \
--do_train=true \
--do_eval=true \
--data_dir=$GLUE_DIR/${TASK_NAME} \
--vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt \
--max_seq_length=128 \
--train_batch_size=32 \
--learning_rate=2e-5 \
--num_train_epochs=3.0 \
--output_dir=${STORAGE_BUCKET}/${TASK_NAME}-output/ \
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu_name=$TPU_NAME \
--model=bert_base \
--dataset=PeerRead \
--frequency=1
```

but I got the error and I couldn't find the solution
I googled it but none of them was my solution to my problem.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that gcloud doesn't pass the value of the $TPU_NAME environment variable. You need to specify your TPU explicitly;

USE:

--tpu=my-tpu

INSTEAD OF:

--tpu=$TPU_NAME